# What can one say about the sequence $(\mathrm{sign}(h_n))$ where $h_0= 2/3$ and $h_n = h_{n-1}^2 - 2$ for every positive $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

There is a sequence given by:$\ \ h(0) = \frac{2}{3} ,\ \ h(n) = h(n-1)^2 - 2 \ \ $for $n \in\mathbb{N^{+}}$.

Let's have a look a the first values:
$$h(0)=\ \ \frac{2}{3}\\ \ \ \ h(1) =-\frac{14}{9}\\ \ \ h(2) = \ \ \frac{34}{81}\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ h(3) =-\frac{11966}{6561} \\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ h(4)=\frac {57091714}{43046721}\\ $$ $...$

Terms are growing fast, I would not post any further.

Interesting for me is the change in the signs. At first glance, do you expect alternating sign changes?

The signs I determined for $ h(n) $ for $n=0..31 \ \ $:

$$ [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1]$$

...then my computer was running out of memory. He needs almost 4 GByte for the last operation.

> Question: Is it possible to determine if $h(n)$ is positive or negative for increasing values of $n$? For example for $n=100$ or even $n=1000000$?
>
> Question: Is it true that for all $h(0)$ with $0<h(0)<2$ and $h(0)$ **not**$ \sqrt{2}$, the signs of $h(n)$ change infinitely often?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are infinitely many initial values for which we get a fixed sign, in fact a fixed function value, after only finitely many terms.  Plug in $h(0)=2\cos (\pi/(2^k))$, where $k$ is a natural numver $\ge 2$ to make the initial value positive, then apply the chronologicaly first answer below.

Comment: I see, it is about an appropriate trigonometric identity. Solve $ \frac{2}{3}=2 \cos(\pi/(2^{k}))$ for $k$. right?

Comment: No, for $2/3$ you have no integer solution for $k$.  If $\theta_0 = arc \cos(1/3)$ is not a rational multiple if $\pi$, the sign changes in your sequence will keep happening forever (but not at regular intervals).

Comment: @MartinHopf: A related question, dealing with the case $h_0 > 2$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073920/explicit-solution-of-the-recursion-x-n-x-n-12-2-with-x-02

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terms are not growing fast, only our attempted representations using primitive operations is.

Assume that $h(k) = 2\cos (\theta(k))$.  This is certainly true for the initial term $k=0$.  Use the appropriate trigonometric identity to show that:

$h(k+1) = 2\cos (2\theta(k))$

and so:

$\theta(n)=2^n\theta(0)$

$h(n) = 2\cos (2^{n}\theta(0))$

Now you can work out the sign pattern easily given any initial value for $h(0)$ or $\theta(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. btw what does $\theta ()$ mean? I'm a bit clueless.

Comment: A variable I introduce for this analysis.  If a term is between -2 and +2, it's twice the cosine of some argument- which I call $\theta$.  We have proof that  $\theta$ doubles from one term to the next the terms $h=2\cos(\theta)$ have to follow suit.